# Magento 2 products image

Tags: magento2, fotorama

I'm getting crazy with product image format in the gallery. I have some images that are 1280x1920 px that magento reduces to 800x1200 px.
The i set the view.xml file, i cleared the pub cached image folder, gave the command  php bin/magento catalog:image:resize and  php bin/magento cache:clean, but the image in the gallery is alway 400x700 px and has white borders in the fotorama stage. How can in fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to below path:

> Your_Theme/etc/view.xml

Add `transparency` to `false`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
            <transparency>false</transparency>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
```

Clear Cache and check White frame should be removed.

Comment: it is ok also if the images are jpg and not png?

Comment: What do you mean by your comment ?

Comment: Sorry i was thinking about the image alpha channel. That thing it  made me crazy, i lost a morning of work trying to fix it

Comment: If it answer helps you might giving me upvote and accept it to help others !! Good Luck !!

Comment: not working man.